# How to match two file from two different folder if the part of the file name matches

Tags: r, substr

I have files with matching strings in their names located in different locations and I need to match them.
Here is what the files looks like,

```
    na_files
    /Users/AS/SAB-M-13.M4DF-2.T-bR.r1-v1_0-ADDFF.0087.cou
   /Users/AS/SAB-M-32.MSFG-2.T-bR.r1-v1_0-ADDFF.3989.cou
  /Users/AS/SAB-M-3.PZT-MOHUA-3.T-bR.r1-v1_0-ADDFF.6188.cou
```

And the following list of files in other directory

```
lb_files
    /Users/DS/SAB-M-13.M4DF-2.T-bR.r1-v1_0-ADDFF.0087.AD.lib
   /Users/DS/SAB-M-32.MSFG-2.T-bR.r1-v1_0-ADDFF.3989.AD.lib
  /Users/DS/SAB-M-3.PZT-MOHUA-3.T-bR.r1-v1_0-ADDFF.6188.AD.lib
```

And I need to match the `na_files` and `lb_files` from both lists, to proceed with.
So I tried, using

```
na_files = grep("cou", list.files(DIR, recursive=T, full.names=T), value=T)
lb_files = grep("lib", list.files(DIR, recursive=T, full.names=T), value=T)
all_patients = NA



 for(curr_file_idx in 1:length(pa_files)){
    curr_file = pat_files[curr_file_idx]
    libsize_file = libsize_files[curr_file_idx]
    curr_pa = data.frame(fread(curr_file))
    pa_id = strsplit(curr_file, "[.][P][Z][T][-]")[[1]][[2]]
    pa_id = substr(patient_id, 1, 5)
    libsize = data.frame(fread(libsize_file))
    pa_id2 = strsplit(libsize_file, "[.][P][Z][T][-]")[[1]][[2]]
    pa_id2 = substr(pa_id2, 1, 5)
    if(patient_id != pa_id2){
      print(pa_id)
      print(pa_id2)
      print("WRONG LB")
      return(1)
    }
```

But this substring pattern only search one file and throws error for the rest.

```
Error in strsplit(curr_file, "[.][P][Z][T][-]")[[1]][[2]] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

I need any regular expression or a pattern which would work for all files. I need the exactly the this part after the period `.M4DF`,  `.MSFG`,  `.MOHUA` should be matching from the three files.

Answer (score 0):

based on your data, extract the file names for `na_files` and `lb_files`

```
na_files<-c("SAB-M-13.M4DF-2.T-bR.r1-v1_0-ADDFF.0087.cou","SAB-M-32.MSFG-2.T-bR.r1-v1_0-ADDFF.3989.cou","SAB-M-3.PZT-MOHUA-3.T-bR.r1-v1_0-ADDFF.6188.cou")
lb_files<-c("SAB-M-13.M4DF-2.T-bR.r1-v1_0-ADDFF.0087.AD.lib","SAB-M-32.MSFG-2.T-bR.r1-v1_0-ADDFF.3989.AD.lib","SAB-M-3.PZT-MOHUA-3.T-bR.r1-v1_0-ADDFF.6188.AD.lib")

na_files_name<-stringi::stri_extract(na_files,regex = "[^.]+") #extracts file name up to first .
lb_files_name<-stringi::stri_extract(lb_files,regex = "[^.]+")


na_files_name %in% lb_files_name #checks the file names match
```

Comment: Sorry I need exactly the part after period to matching with files from two directories. For example M4DF, MSFG and MOHUA

Comment: this is tricky as your file name patter isn't consistent as MOHUA as PZT- preceding it.